# Strange behaviour of String class' next! method on unicode strings

Tags: ruby, unicode

I have ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-linux]
When I run the following code:

```
char = "\u00D7"

(1..10).each {
    puts char.bytes.collect { |b| b.ord }.inspect
    puts char
    char.next!
}
```

I get the following output:

```
[195, 151]
×
[195, 152]
Ø
[195, 153]
Ù
[195, 154]
Ú
[195, 155]
Û
[195, 156]
Ü
[195, 157]
Ý
[195, 158]
Þ
[195, 159]
ß
[195, 160]
à
```

But, when I initialize char to `\u00D6` instead, as below:

```
char = "\u00D6"

(1..10).each {
    puts char.bytes.collect { |b| b.ord }.inspect
    puts char
    char.next!
}
```

I get the following:

```
[195, 150]
Ö
[195, 128, 195, 128]
ÀÀ
[195, 128, 195, 129]
ÀÁ
[195, 128, 195, 130]
ÀÂ
[195, 128, 195, 131]
ÀÃ
[195, 128, 195, 132]
ÀÄ
[195, 128, 195, 133]
ÀÅ
[195, 128, 195, 134]
ÀÆ
[195, 128, 195, 135]
ÀÇ
[195, 128, 195, 136]
ÀÈ
```

Why is the behaviour so different in each case?

Comment: Unicode collation order is complicated stuff and string#succ does some complicated stuff of its own ( eg 'z'.succ #=> "aa". Neither (in general) is a simple as just adding 1 to the codepoint

Answer (score 0):

Here is my basic understanding of this problem.

Unicode characters should be sorted according to the unicode collation algorithm. [Collation Table](http://www.unicode.org/charts/uca/). [Apparently](https://github.com/ninjudd/icunicode), Ruby does not do this correctly. I checked in previous versions and experienced the same error. The collation would also affect the `next`/`succ` methods.

In order to get appropriate unicode collation, try the [TwitterCLDR](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-cldr-rb#sorting-collation), which contains an implementation of the sorting collation.

In order to make your original code work as expected, try something like this

```
char = "\u00D6"

10.times do
    puts char.bytes.collect { |b| b.ord }.inspect
    puts char
    char = char.b.next.force_encoding("UTF-8")
end
```

The [`b`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-b) converts the string into ASCII-8BIT, we then increment and convert back. It's complicated, but it works.